# Unable to import angular-ui-bootstrap in my application using webpack

Tags: angularjs, webpack, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am trying to import 'angular-ui-bootstrap' in the vendor.ts file.

I keep getting can not resolve angular-ui-bootstrap.

Any suggestions on how to get around this problem.

I want to remove the reference from my index.html and move it to the Vendor.ts file which webpack uses to bundle vendor files.

Thanks

Comment: please share some code to see what you have tried so far.

Comment: Got it working. I was using an outdated angular-ui-bootstrap node_module. Once I upgraded everything went good.

Comment: show me too! please